# Removing character strings from dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove rows with character strings (exact matches) from the second column in a dataframe:

Input:

```
   >data

      habitat       species
         wet species1_ind1
         wet species1_ind1
         dry species2_ind1
         dry species2_ind1
         dry species3_ind1
         dry species3_ind1
         ...
```

Desired output (with row containing species2_ind1 removed):

```
    >new_data

      habitat       species
         wet species1_ind1
         wet species1_ind1
         dry species3_ind1
         dry species3_ind1
         ...
```

Ideally I'd like to supply a list of character strings to remove from the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `%in%`

```
data[!(data$species %in% c("species2_ind1")), ]
  habitat       species
1     wet species1_ind1
2     wet species1_ind1
5     dry species3_ind1
6     dry species3_ind1
```

**Details:**
This is selecting the rows where `species` is not in the list. Data has both rows and columns.  When you specify `data[x,y]` x gives the rows and y gives the columns. `data[x, ]` means that you have specified the rows with x but take all columns. The above expression takes all columns, but specifies the rows as `!(data$species %in% c("species2_ind1"))`.
`data$species %in% c("species2_ind1"))` gives those rows for which the value of data$species is in the list.  But those are the ones we want to exclude, so we use `!` to negate the logical expression and get the rows where `data$species` is *not* on the list.

Comment: What is the purpose of the exclamation point and comma after c("species2_ind1"))?

Comment: Will add to answer.

Comment: When you delete rows 3:4, can the output then go from 1:4 instead of 1:2 and 5:6, skipping the deleted rows?

Comment: The row numbers will be as above, but if you want them to just be one-up numbered, after deleting 3&4 you can use `row.names(data) = 1:nrow(data)`